# How to use precompiled ports collection with pkgng?

Tags: freebsd

I am trying `pkgng` to install `postfix`.

```
# pkg install postfix
Updating repository catalogue
Repository catalogue is up-to-date, no need to fetch fresh copy
pkg: Package 'postfix' was not found in the repositories
```

But it seems the default configuration doesn't search precompiled ports collection on FreeBSD site. How can I make it to install from remote site?

I am using FreeBSD 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FreeBSD suspended `pkg` repository due to a security issue.](https://wiki.freebsd.org/pkgng)

> Availability of binary pkgs for Download
>
> While pkg works just fine with ports as the local package management
>   tool, it ultimately allows to skip ports and use remote binary
>   packages.
>
> As a consequence of the security incident on 11th November 2012, for
>   the time being pre-compiled packages for pkgng are not available from
>   any official FreeBSD repository. The test repository
>   pkgbeta.freebsd.org contains only a copy of pkg-1.0.X.txz in order to
>   facilitate the bootstrap procedure for enabling pkgng on a new system.
>
> Package build clusters are now setup and running weekly. Packages
>   should be available for the FreeBSD 10 release.
>
> In the mean time, pkg users who wish to have binary packages are
>   advised to investigate tools such as poudriere or tinderbox.

We I think the only way is just waiting for FreeBSD 10 release.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [thread](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2013-September/253368.html) may help a bit. Basically, add the pkg-test repo to your pkg config.